# Looking for a SQL injection demonstration

Tags: asp-classic, sql-injection

I'm a web applications developer, using Classic ASP as server side script.

I always protect my apps from SQL injection by using a simple function to double single apostrophe for string parameters.

```
Function ForSQL(strString)  
  ForSQL = Replace(strString, "'", "''")  
End Function
```

For numeric parameters, I use the CInt, CLng and CDbl functions.

I often write concatenated query; I don't always use stored procedure and I don't always validate user inputs.

I'd like to ask you if someone can show me a working attack against this line of code:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Id FROM tUsers WHERE Username='" & _
         ForSQL(Left(Request.Form("Username"),20)) & "' AND Password='" & _ 
         ForSQL(Left(Request.Form("Username"),20)) & "'"
```

It could be a banality but I've never found a kind of attack that works.

Comment: I asked a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506574/sql-injection-isnt-replace-good-enough

Comment: http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=9397

Answer (score 0):

I've always found "sqli helper 2.7" (you can download it) to find most/all SQL injections. I'm not sure if this will help at all, but it will at least help test for all of the SQL comments and everything. I remember on one of my sites it found a main SQL injection to dumb all of my database data. It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it might be able to find a way through.

Answer (score -3):

There is no functioning SQL injection for input sanitized this way. The downside is retrieving data from the database is you have to replace on double apostrophes.

```
sDataRetrievedFromDatabase = Replace(sDataRetrievedFromDatabase, "''", "'")
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your answer. I'm italian, maybe I cannot understand english in correct way. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: I see your example. But I cannot understand why I have to replace the double apostrophes to a single apostroph. When I write an double apos in the db... It considers only one.

Comment: In my experience this is not the case. When I return the data I need to do this replace to return the data to single apostrophe.

Comment: With MS SQL Server if you INSERT INTO Temp(Field1) ('''') the DB saves only one single quote. If you SELECT * FROM Temp the result is only ' (a single quote, not two)... so... no need to replace...

Comment: This is incorrect.  See the link that Mr Lister posted as a comment to the question for some examples.