# Can this simple String escaping prevent any SQL Injections?

Tags: java, sql, security, jdbc, sql-injection

I'm working at a company where the person responsible for the database module is strictly against using prepared statements. I'm worrying that his implementation is not secure.

Here is the code we are currently using to make a SQL query (Java 8 Application with JDBC/MySQL 5.5):

```
String value = "Raw user input over HTTP-Form";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM db1.articles WHERE title like '" + 
replaceSingleQuotes(value) + "'";
executeSQL(sql);

public static String replaceSingleQuotes(String value) {
  value = value.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
  return value.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'");
}
```

I was not able to come up with any injections but his solution seems very fishy to me. Can anyone point out any way how this escaping could be circumvented? He will not replace his code if I can't come up with anything and we have very sensitive information of thousands of customers in our application (banking).

Edit:
Unfortunately i can't show executeSQL() because there is a mess with a huge class hierarchy and everything is scattered. But it comes down to something like this:

```
String query = ... // query escaped with the above function
java.sql.Connection connection = ...
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: You did not include the `replaceSingleQuotes()` method.  Yes, this is probably a bad idea.  Even if you get away with it now, down the road a small refactor could introduce an injection opportunity.

Comment: Should that person be fired for intentionally creating a vulnerability in your system?

Comment: Against using prepared statements? Well that's a first. Also congratulations on having such a guy responsible for the database module.

Comment: Better use PreparedStatement without string concatenation as above. The above code would be better done by `replace("\\", "\\\\")`. Argue about readability too.

Comment: Seriously though, you need to raise an issue about that. You can't have people "strictly against" tried and true methods of operation. If you're really in banking, I can't believe that would pass audit.

Comment: Maybe it's not the best idea to make the guy who's selling you hardware also responsible for the database module. Besides the security thing not using prepared statements does also has impact on performance in most cases.

Imagine this is a mission critical statement that is called very often. Everytime your database engine has to parse it and must calculate execution paths - this is unnecessary work that only heats your datacenter.

Comment: Very simple. Email it to the media as anonymous source if the higher ups wont listen. blow the wistle. It's fricking banking! you dont play with other peoples lives/data/money. Here in the netherlands the banks got robbed of millions during an attack. There are so many attack vectors possible with this. limit it.

Comment: `PreparedStatement` don't simply offer security, but also performance with pre-compiled query, batch, readability, ... If your "DB admin" (or pseudo admin...) is against, ask him the reason. I can guarante it wouldn't be able to find good reason to forbide the usage. Of course, I have seen (in banking) some DEV using a `PreparedStatement` with a concatenate `String` ... not knowing how to used it. I hope that guy is the same. Raise a security issues, if you have to, contact the audit/compliance/secutiry department about that problem (if you prefer, don't write, talk, it leave less trace ;) )

Comment: The problem here isn't whether this code is secure or not. The problem is if the person will rather use his own "solutions" over industry standards, he probably has other quirks as well. This is a serious security issue, you wouldn't let the guy build his own bank vaults either.

Comment: Oh, just use a PreparedStatement like everyone else who cares about security.

Comment: I would recommend looking for a different job, if you cannot sort out this issue with your manager. The person responsible for the database module is an idiot and is causing a serious risk to the business. If management are unwilling to deal with this as well, you're better off at a place where they don't have their heads in the sand.

Comment: The burden of proof here is on the idiot.  He needs to prove to management that his non-standard solution is secure.  It can't possibly be over to you to find a vulnerability.  I don't mean to belittle your credentials, but if I were a customer of your bank (oh, hell, I'm not a customer am I?  What bank is it?),  I'd want my money protected better than "well, we've got one programmer here who didn't find any vulnerability, so it must be perfectly safe".

Comment: And to answer your question, you'd need to show the `executeSQL` method.  It's really not clear what's going to happen to all those extra backslashes.

Comment: From what I can see, the only vulnerability I see is that you need to replace EVERY VALUE INSERTED in those DB to match you research. If the `title` contains `\\ ` it would need to be `\\\\ ` to be able to find it ... so every values inserted are converted ... that is a lot of processing that is not needed. Also, 2 `replaceAll` can cost a lot of time, especially since this is done on EVERY queries. So the vulnaribilites I see, "time consumption", I know it doesn't look important but where I am, some process take almost 12hour to end, I am sure because of things like this....

Comment: Unicode hacks are fun https://siderite.blogspot.com/2013/01/why-doubling-single-quotes-is-not.html#atEXECUpdateMyTableNDROPTABLEmyTable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL injection: isn't replace("'", "''") good enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506574/sql-injection-isnt-replace-good-enough)

Comment: What kind of bank uses MySQL as their database and rank amateurs as their developers? This whole question sounds fishy. \*puts on X-Files goggles\*

Comment: @Kayaman every bank is different. There are many departments and some  have their own software development sub-department. At least that is the short story. Ours happens to use MySQL (MyISAM only, yay!). In Germany there is a serious skill shortage, so there are mostly amateurs available on the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method of attack would be by "loading" the attack.

First, you inject as user name, bank transfer message, whatever into it

> transfer 0.01
>   to:    02020.020202.200202
>   name:  johnny tables';drop table foobar  --

will be escaped to

```
johnny tables\';drop table foobar  --
```

So far so good. protection in effect. our attach failed. We try the loading attack.

Now we are going to make a scheduled payment order.

This is assuming a common error is made, that once inserted in the database, the value is "safe" because it has been checked once.

> transfer 0.01
>   to:    02020.020202.200202
>   name:  johnny tables';drop table foobar--
>   schedule: 1 day from now

Storing the order in the db

```
'johnny tables\';drop table foobar--'
```

will be stored as

> johnny tables';drop table foobar--

Now at midnight the scheduler kicks in and starts iterating the scheduled payments

```
select name from scheduled where time > x and < y
```

so the bank code starts to chrunch

```
String name = result['name'];
String acct = result['acct'];
String amt = result['amt'];
string query = "insert into payment_process (name,acct,amt) values('"+name+"','"+acct+"','"+amt+"');
```

and boom, your table is dropped. `*`

When you go the manual route, you have to ensure all, each and every instance of the variable is escaped, that all unicode characters are accounted for, that all idiocrancies of the database engine are accounted for.

Also, using prepared statements can give a significant speed boost, because you don't have to rebuild queries. You can just build them once, store them in a cache and just swap out the parameters.
Especially when iterating large lists they are a godsent.

The root problem is that he probably doesn't understand prepared statements, doesn't *get* them how they work. Insecurity triggered can make aggressive and protective of a certain way, even fanatical, just to prevent to admit you just don't know how they work.
Try to talk to him about it, if he doesn't wish to listen to reason go to his manager and explain the issue, and that if the site/app gets hacked, it will be on the head of your co-worker and your manager, and tell him the risks are HUGE. Point to the recent hacks where a lot of money was stolen like the swift hack.

`*` *May not actually work, dependent on actual query, joins, unions etc.. it's a very simplified example*

Comment: From what I see, I guess the "API" proposed will unsafe the data each time it is read (to be used normally), so it would not be used just like that. But if my guess is wrong, this would be a really nice security issue! Never seen it in action, but I like this attack!

Comment: I was under the impression that this is a standard way to hack into a database where they use this kind of security :-) but that is because i've seen code other coders(that get paid way more than me)  use and I spot the flaw in security, because I don't want my boss screaming at me :-)
Believe me when I say, that the internet has more holes than a sieve, and coders like the colleague of OP are more common than people who come with the times. I know of a flight engine where I could wipe the entire database with one query... I told my boss, let them use prepared statements or I refuse to use it