# PreparedStatement with if else

Tags: java, sql

I have this code

```
            sql="update rpttbl set salary= ?";
            PreparedStatement presptStmt2=conCreate.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=rptStmt.executeQuery("select temp from rpttbl");
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                rs2=st.executeQuery("select sa8 from sarchive where sempid="+rs.getString(1)+" and "
                        + "(sdate='"+Globals.year+"-"+Globals.date+"-28' or sdate='0000-00-00')");        
                if(!rs2.next()){
                    System.out.println("no records");
                    presptStmt2.setString(1,"000");
                    presptStmt2.addBatch();
                }  
                else{
                    System.out.println(rs2.getString(1));
                    presptStmt2.setString(1,rs2.getString(1));
                    presptStmt2.addBatch();
                }

            }
            presptStmt2.executeBatch();
```

after the execution, the (salary) column for all rows is "000". 
It seems that the prepStmt2 in else block never executed but (rs2.getString(1)) works just fine.

Any help please

Comment: how does it seems it is never executed?

Comment: my table shows the value of the (salary) field is 000 for all rows

Comment: Why would you batch `update rpttbl set salary = ?;`? Rewrite your code. That's terrible, you're trying to do 3 things at once.

Comment: @Sana'aAla'a ... ok, and what did you expect? have you tried debugging your code? what does your "select sa8 ..." query return?

Comment: I'm really beginner, so can you clarify what is the problem please

Comment: if you are a beginner, start at the beginning. don't try to go for persistence (stop using a DB, for starters). We are trying to get YOU to tell US what the actual problem is

Comment: "select sa8 ..." returns right values from the table, I checked that. But I do not know why prepStmt works in if and dose not in else

Comment: FYI: you execute two SELECT to update one table (all row of the table.. without a condition), you should use one query instead.

Comment: @Sana'aAla'a have you verified that the else block is actually triggered? prepStmt doesn't "do" anything in either if or else block, you are merely configuring it.

Comment: @user75ponic don't give bad advice to people. There's no reason to use stored procedures for everything. In fact care should be taken when they're used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update query doesn't have a condition :

```
update rpttbl set salary= ?
```

It will execute this query in a batch but only the last execution will matter since you update every rows with the same `salary` value.

Add a condition to that query and update the logic to add that ID to the `PreparedStatement`

```
update rpttbl set salary= ? where some_id = ?
```

And

```
prepStmt2.set***(2, <someId>);
```

---

FYI: You should not trust your data like this :

```
rs2=st.executeQuery("select sa8 from sarchive where sempid="+rs.getString(1)+" and "
                    + "(sdate='"+Globals.year+"-"+Globals.date+"-28' or sdate='0000-00-00')");
```

You are using `PreparedStatement` so you are aware of SQL Injection but you could find some injection possible when you concatenate value from the DB itself. Never thrust a `String` in SQL.
Use a `PreparedStatement` instead and pass the parameter with the bind parameters available.

We had this conversation yesterday on [Can this simple String escaping prevent any SQL Injections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48861737/4391450) with a [answer from Tschallacka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48862570/4391450).